# Laravel strange query doesn't want to work

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4

I'm trying to get he username of the table `comments`, but it doesn't work so good.

First of all, when I execute the query

```
select `comments`.`username` from `comments` inner join `threads` on `comments`.`tid` = `threads`.`tid` where `comments`.`deleted_at` is null and `threads`.`cid` = 4 order by `comments`.`posted_at` desc limit 1
```

it does return the value it needs to return.

Remind, the number `4` in this query stands for a int();

Now I tried so many things to get this work propperly in Laravel, but it doesn't...

So I have a `foreach` loop in my view and this needs to display the username from `comments.username`.

How can I do this.

Every time I try something I get array to sting, or something else.

The `id` for `cid` is called with `$categorie->id`.

This is my code:

```
@foreach($categories as $categorie)
              @if($categorie->fid == $forum->fid)
              <td class="topic-marker-forum">
                <i class="fa fa-comments fa-3x"></i>
              </td>

              <td class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                <div><a href="Categorie-{{ Str::slug($categorie->name) }}" title="{{ $categorie->name }}"><strong>{{ $categorie->name }}</strong></a></div>
                <div class=""><em>{{ $categorie->description }}</em></div>

              </td>

              <td class="col-md-1 col-sm-1 text-right"><span class="badge">{{ Thread::where('cid', '=', $categorie->id)->remember(15)->count() }}</span></td>

              <td class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 ">
                <div>
                  @if(Thread::where('cid', '=', $categorie->id)->exists() && Comment::join('threads', 'comments.tid', '=', 'threads.tid')->where('threads.cid', '=', $categorie->id)->orderBy('comments.posted_at', 'DESC')->exists())
                    <a href="{{ Config::get('app.url') }}/Thread-{{ Thread::where('cid', '=', $categorie->id)->orderBy('date_posted', 'DESC')->pluck('slug') }}">{{ Helper::HTMLFilter(Thread::where('cid', '=', $categorie->id)->orderBy('date_posted', 'DESC')->pluck('title')) }}</a><br>

                    <i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> {{ \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', Comment::join('threads', 'comments.tid', '=', 'threads.tid')->where('threads.cid', '=', $categorie->id)->orderBy('comments.posted_at', 'DESC')->pluck('posted_at'))->format('d/m/Y H:i') }}<br>

                    <i class="fa fa-user"></i> <a href="{{ Config::get('app.url') }}/User-query here">query here</a>
                  @else
                  <b>-</b>
                  @endif
                </div>
              </td>
            </tr>
            @endif
            @endforeach
```

I really don't know how I can solve this problem.

---

## Edit

Controller (ForumController):

```
public function index()
    {
        $forums = Forums::orderBy('disp_order', 'asc')->get();
        $categories = Categorie::orderBy('disp_order', 'asc')->get();

        return View::make('index')->with('forums', $forums)->with('categories', $categories);
    }
```

Models:

```
class Comment extends Eloquent
{
    use SoftDeletingTrait;

    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];

    protected $table = 'comments';

    public $timestamps = false;

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('User', 'uid');
    }

}
```

```
class Thread extends Eloquent
{
    use SoftDeletingTrait;

    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];

    protected $table = 'threads';

    public $timestamps = false;
}
```

The error I get when I do this:

```
{{ DB::statement('select `comments`.`username` from `comments` inner join `threads` on `comments`.`tid` = `threads`.`tid` where `comments`.`deleted_at` is null and `threads`.`cid` = '. $categorie->id .' order by `comments`.`posted_at` desc limit 1') }}
```

This just returns `1` But I need the `username`.

When I do this:

```
{{Comment::join('threads', 'comments.tid', '=', 'threads.tid')->where('threads.cid', '=', $categorie->id)->orderBy('comments.posted_at', 'DESC')->limit(1)->pluck('username')}}
```

Error:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'username' in field list is ambiguous (SQL: select `username` from `comments` inner join `threads` on `comments`.`tid` = `threads`.`tid` where `comments`.`deleted_at` is null and `threads`.`cid` = 3 order by `comments`.`posted_at` desc limit 1)
```

When I use this:

```
{{Comment::join('threads', 'comments.tid', '=', 'threads.tid')->where('threads.cid', '=', $categorie->id)->orderBy('comments.posted_at', 'DESC')->first()->pluck('username')}}
```

it doesn't return any error, but it also doesn't display the correct value?

Comment: paste controller and model code, and error which are you getting if you are getting.

Comment: I've updated my question.